# Why is there a special type deduction rule for auto and braced initializers in C++11/C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, c++14, initializer-list

In his CppCon 2014 talke ["Type Deduction and Why You Care"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQxj20X-tIU), Scott Meyers raises the question why there is a special rule about `auto` and braced initializers in the C++11/C++14 standard (his question starts [at 36m05s](http://youtu.be/wQxj20X-tIU?t=36m5s)).

The semantic of auto in combination with a braced-init-list is defined in §7.1.6.4/6.

---

I thought about it and could not come up with a use-case either. The closest thing that I have seen so far is one example where Bjarne Stroustrup used it.

In his [Cpp 2014 talk "Make Simple Tasks Simple!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nesCaocNjtQ), he once uses `auto` to capture initializers (but only as a workaround).

Here is the code (part of slide 30, [at 37m10s](http://youtu.be/nesCaocNjtQ?t=37m10s)):

```
    // auto ss1 = collect({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }, odd); // error: Bummer!
    auto lst = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    auto ss2 = collect(lst, odd);    // {1,3,5}
```

But note that it is only a workaround. He mentioned that it should not be necessary. Instead he would prefer to directly pass the arguments to the function. So, it cannot really serve as a good motivation for `auto` and initializer lists.

---

My understanding of C++ is not deep enough to judge the downsides of allowing initializer-lists in Bjarne's example, as he proposes. Anyway, it would avoid the need for `auto` in that case.

So, is `auto` and initializer list only a workaround for something that could have been better solved? Or are there good examples, where the extra auto deduction rule in §7.1.6.4/6 is useful?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a C++1z proposal to make `auto x = {expr};` use the type of `expr` (minus allowing a non-parenthesized comma operator). I'm not sure what other type to use for a full list, though.

Comment: @christ I think you mean N3922. Scott Meyers mentions that, too. Visual Studio already implements it, even though it is not part of C++14. Here is the link: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html

Comment: Ah, that's the one. Although I *kind of* have to disagree with the general one due to this usage. I would really prefer that to be ill-formed and initializer lists be able to be passed into functions without the extra line, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rationale is in [N2640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf), which wanted to ban deduction of a plain type parameter from a braced initializer list in general:

> ```
> template<class T>
> void inc(T, int); // (1)
>
> template<class T>
> void inc(std::initializer_list<T>, long); // (2)
>
> inc({1, 2, 3}, 3); // Calls (2). (If deduction had succeeded
>                    // for (1), (1) would have been called — a
>                    // surprise.)
> ```

But carved out a special exception for `auto`:

> On the other hand, being able to deduce an `initializer_list<X>` for
>   `T` is attractive to  allow:
>
> ```
> auto x = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 };
> f(x);
> g(x);
> ```
>
> which was deemed desirable behavior since the very beginning of the
>   EWG discussions about  initializer lists. Rather than coming up with a
>   clever deduction rule for a parameter type `T` matched with a {}-list 
>   (an option we pursued in earlier sketches and drafts of this paper),
>   we now prefer to handle this  with a special case for "auto" variable
>   deduction when the initializer is a {}-list. I.e., for the  specific
>   case of a variable declared with an "auto" type specifier and a
>   {}-list initializer, the "auto"  is deduced as for a function
>   `f(initializer_list<T>)` instead of as for a function `f(T)`.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Meyers addressed the topic in a blog post: [Why auto deduces std::initializer_list for a braced initializer](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2015/02/why-auto-deduces-stdinitializerlist-for.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Like T.C.'s answer, it also refers to [N2640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf). The special deduction rule has been added to allow code like this to work:

```
 auto x = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 };
 f(x);
 g(x);
```

In the blog post, Scott cites the following explanation from James Hopkin:

> The short story is that [N2640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf) proposed the special case that auto should deduce braced initializers as initializer_lists, without realizing that doing so broke uniform initialization (e.g. it makes `int x{7};` and `auto x{7};` very different). [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) fixes that by (of course!) introducing another special case: single parameter braced initializers have their own rule.
>
> Slightly more detail: [N2640](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2640.pdf) tries to keep template argument deduction simple but attempts to allow a braced initializer to be passed to two or more functions via assigning it to an auto. This got turned into wording in [N2672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2672.htm). Note that Stroustrup's previous design in [N2532](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2532.pdf) allows deduction of initializer_lists for both unconstrained template parameters and auto, which is more consistent but also breaks uniform initialization.
>
> None of this explains why [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) didn't just remove the special case for auto. That wouldn't have resulted in silent changes to the meaning of code and would have simplified the language.